CSV not appending with each cycle (MicroPython)
I am attempting to make a data logger that updates a CSV on Google Drive as well as a file on an SD card. I would like the file on the SD card to update with a new entry at each cycle. The following code does not write a new line to the existing file. When the script is stopped, the file only contains the last entry. What am I missing?
The script is as follows:
import network
import urequests
from machine import ADC, Pin
import time
import machine, onewire, ds18x20
import os
import sdcard
import uos

# Initialize the SD card
def initialize_sd_card():
    cs = machine.Pin(1, machine.Pin.OUT)  # Chip select pin
    spi = machine.SPI(0, baudrate=1000000, polarity=0, phase=0,
                      bits=8, firstbit=machine.SPI.MSB,
                      sck=machine.Pin(2), mosi=machine.Pin(3), miso=machine.Pin(4))
    sd = sdcard.SDCard(spi, cs)
    vfs = uos.VfsFat(sd)
    uos.mount(vfs, "/sd")
    print("SD card initialized and mounted.")

# Connect to network function
def connect_to_wifi():
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)

    ssid = 'WLAN-770906'
    password = '99124920927124845873'
    wlan.connect(ssid, password)

    # Wait until connected
    while not wlan.isconnected():
        print("Connecting to WiFi...")
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Connected to WiFi:", wlan.ifconfig())
    return wlan

# Internal temperature sensor is connected to ADC channel 4
temp_sensor = ADC(4)

def read_internal_temperature():
    adc_value = temp_sensor.read_u16()
    voltage = adc_value * (3.3 / 65535.0)
    temperature_celsius = 27 - (voltage - 0.706) / 0.001721
    return temperature_celsius

# Initialize DS18B20
ds_pin = machine.Pin(28)  # Make sure this pin is correct
ds_sensor = ds18x20.DS18X20(onewire.OneWire(ds_pin))

# Soil moisture sensor setup
soil = ADC(Pin(26))  # Soil moisture PIN reference
min_moisture = 24614
max_moisture = 48795  # Calibration value (min)

# Function to read soil moisture
def read_soil_moisture():
    moisture = (max_moisture - soil.read_u16()) * 100 / (max_moisture - min_moisture)
    print("Moisture: " + "%.2f" % moisture + "% (ADC: " + str(soil.read_u16()) + ")")
    return moisture

# Function to log temperature data to a comma-delimited text file
def log_temperature(data_to_send):
    file_name = "/sd/temperature_log.txt"  # Use .txt for comma-delimited text

    try:
        # Check if the file exists, if not create it with a header
        if file_name not in uos.listdir("/sd"):
            with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
                file.write('Date,Time,Internal Temperature (°C),DS18B20_1 Temperature (°C),DS18B20_2 Temperature (°C),Soil Moisture (%)\n')

        # Append temperature data to the file
        with open(file_name, 'a') as file:  # Append mode
            file.write('{},{},{:.2f},{:.2f},{:.2f},{:.2f}\n'.format(
                data_to_send['date'], 
                data_to_send['time'], 
                data_to_send['temperature'], 
                data_to_send['temperature_ds1'],
                data_to_send['temperature_ds2'],
                data_to_send['Soil_moisture']
            ))
            file.flush()  # Ensure data is written to disk immediately

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error logging temperature:", e)

# Function to attempt to send data
def send_data_to_webhook(data_to_send):
    url = "https://hook.eu1.make.com/cxyhxctngdmc1ohme35cxln7fi9s7rjm"
    try:
        print("Sending data to webhook:", data_to_send)
        r = urequests.post(url, json=data_to_send, timeout=20)
        print("Response status code:", r.status_code)
        print("Response:", r.text)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error sending data:", e)

# Attempt to reconnect if WLAN is disconnected
def reconnect_wifi(wlan):
    if not wlan.isconnected():
        print("WiFi connection lost. Attempting to reconnect...")
        connect_to_wifi()

# Main loop
wlan = connect_to_wifi()  # Establish initial connection
initialize_sd_card()  # Initialize SD card

while True:
    # Fetch current UTC date and time
    time_data = {}
    try:
        print("Fetching time data from date.jsontest.com...")
        time_response = urequests.get("http://date.jsontest.com", timeout=20)
        
        print("Time API response status code:", time_response.status_code)
        if time_response.status_code == 200:
            time_data = time_response.json()
            print("Current time data:", time_data)
            
            # Extract the date and time from the response
            utc_time_str = time_data["time"]  # e.g., "07:10:36 PM"
            utc_date_str = time_data["date"]  # e.g., "2023-09-25"
            
            # Convert the time string to 24-hour format for easier manipulation
            utc_hour, utc_minute, utc_second = map(int, utc_time_str[:-3].split(':'))
            if 'PM' in utc_time_str and utc_hour != 12:
                utc_hour += 12
            if 'AM' in utc_time_str and utc_hour == 12:
                utc_hour = 0

            # Convert to CEST (UTC + 2)
            cest_hour = (utc_hour + 2) % 24
            cest_time_str = "{:02}:{:02}:{:02}".format(cest_hour, utc_minute, utc_second)
            print("Converted CEST time:", cest_time_str)

        else:
            print("Failed to fetch time data. Status code:", time_response.status_code)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error fetching time data:", e)

    # Read internal temperature
    temperatureC = read_internal_temperature()

    # Give the sensor a moment to settle
    time.sleep(2)

    # Scan for DS devices
    roms = ds_sensor.scan()
    print('Found DS devices:', roms)

    temp_ds1 = None  # Default value in case DS18B20_1 temperature is not read
    temp_ds2 = None  # Default value in case DS18B20_2 temperature is not read

    if not roms:
        print("No DS devices found. Please check the connections.")
    else:
        ds_sensor.convert_temp()
        time.sleep_ms(750)  # Allow time for conversion

        for idx, rom in enumerate(roms):
            temp = ds_sensor.read_temp(rom)
            if temp is not None:
                if idx == 0:
                    temp_ds1 = temp
                    print("Sensor 1 (ROM: {}): Temperature: {:.2f}°C".format(rom, temp))
                elif idx == 1:
                    temp_ds2 = temp
                    print("Sensor 2 (ROM: {}): Temperature: {:.2f}°C".format(rom, temp))
            else:
                print("Failed to read temperature for ROM:", rom)

    # Read soil moisture
    moisture = read_soil_moisture()

    # Prepare data to send and log
    data_to_send = {
        "temperature": float(temperatureC) if temperatureC is not None else 0.0,  # Ensure a valid float
        "date": utc_date_str if utc_date_str else "N/A",  # Handle missing date
        "time": cest_time_str if cest_time_str else "N/A",  # Handle missing time
        "temperature_ds1": float(temp_ds1) if temp_ds1 is not None else 0.0,  # Ensure a valid float for DS18B20_1 temperature
        "temperature_ds2": float(temp_ds2) if temp_ds2 is not None else 0.0,  # Ensure a valid float for DS18B20_2 temperature
        "Soil_moisture": float(moisture) if moisture is not None else 0.0  # Ensure valid float for soil moisture
    }

    # Log the data to the text file
    log_temperature(data_to_send)

    # Check if WLAN is still connected, if not reconnect
    reconnect_wifi(wlan)

    # Attempt to send the data if connected
    if wlan.isconnected():
        send_data_to_webhook(data_to_send)
    else:
        print("WiFi disconnected, skipping data send to webhook.")

    # Wait for 60 seconds before the next iteration
    print("Waiting for 60 seconds...")
    time.sleep(60)  # Adjust the wait time as needed




If uos.listdir just returns file names (not full paths) then "/sd/temperature_log.txt" won't be in that list. But "temperature_log.txt" will.

Thats done it, Thank you
